# Pass a variable by reference to a function in Ruby

Tags: ruby, methods, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference

I would like to pass a variable by reference to a function.
In this way, in this function the variable can be modified and the new value will be available also in the part of the program

e.g.

In soft_1.rb

```
 func=Remote::CheckPart.new()  # function defined in check.rb
 warning=""
 out=func.check(warning)
 puts "New Warning #{warning}!"
```

In check.rb

```
def check(warning)
    warning << "WARNING DUE TO SOME EVENT!"
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot pass by reference to ruby.

On the other hand, `String` in ruby is not immutable, so using `<<` actually *changes the string you are passing* - so your code actually works as you wanted it to:

```
class Remote::CheckPart
  def check(warning)
    warning << "WARNING DUE TO SOME EVENT!"
  end
end

func=Remote::CheckPart.new()
warning=""
out=func.check(warning)
puts "New Warning #{warning}!"
```

will actually output:

`New Warning WARNING DUE TO SOME EVENT!!`